# Error: The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (Cannot launch conpty)

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, build, esp-idf

I have installed VS code and have added the ESP-IDF extension to it. When I build the hello world example code of ESP-IDF, the code gets stuck in building, and I get the following error regarding the terminal:

[image]

How do I fix this issue?